# Possibility to overlay dots on the end points of the lines created with the path tool

Tags: pine-script

Just wanted to check if there was any way to systematically overlay all path drawing endpoints with dots on them.  I've provided a screenshot showing what I would like to see.

If this is possible, can you point me in the right direction on how it could be achieved?

Thanks in advance!

[path with dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PydYS.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you obtain the endpoint value during the current active bar you can use a boolean variable to track when an endpoint occurs eg `endpointnow` and use `plot()` like this :

```
plot(endpoint, style = plot.style_circles, color = endpointnow ? color.blue : #00000000, linewidth = 5)
```

This will plot a blue circle at the value of the endpoint, but set the color invisible if the current bar isn't an endpoint.

If you're working with something like pivots, where the endpoint only becomes confirmed after the endpoint bar, you will have to use the `label()` functions in order to place the circle on a historical bar.

```
label.new(x = endpoint_bar_index, y = endpoint_price, style = label.style_circle, color = color.blue, size = size.small)
```

Comment: Wonderful thanks.  Let me play around with that.